# Proc SQL - Subquery for column select

Tags: proc-sql

I have two tables, one has hundreds of variables and I'm only interested in a few dozen.

The other is a single column whose values are the exact names of the variables I'm interested in from the first table.

I need to extract variables from the first table, and I'm trying to avoid using the keep statement in base SAS. I'm thinking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 as
SELECT (SELECT var FROM table2)
FROM table3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `keep` statement is probably your best best.  There might be a way to setup a macro, but I don't think this is possible using only `proc sql`.

Comment: There's gotta be a better way as I've done this in Stata. I actually have to iterate this on 20 different tables, so the keep statement is not ideal.